# Connecting to Remote DB2 Database (JSP)

Tags: database, jsp, db2

Let me preface this by saying I am completely new at this kind of thing. Anyways..

I am trying to connect to a DB2 Database. 
The server is running Ubuntu 12.04 and Apache Tomcat 7. The driver db2jcc.jar is included in the build path.

Here is my JSP code:

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<% Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");%>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>db2 connection</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<%
  String url = 
  "jdbc:db2://IP_ADDR:60000/INST1" +
  ":user=USERNAME;password=PASSWORD;" +
  "traceLevel=" +
  (com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2BaseDataSource.TRACE_ALL) + ";";
  Connection con = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url);
%>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

The error message I am getting:

> The application server rejected establishment of the connection.
>   An attempt was made to access a database, INST1, which was either not found or does not support transactions. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08004

I checked out the IBM Support page on the issue here: 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21443723

It mentions using the target directory name, found by issuing the `db2 list dcs directory` command.

On the server, mine was initially blank, but I created an entry using the `db2 catalog dcs database DB2INST1 as INST1` command.

Now my output for using db2 list dcs directory` is as follows:

> Database Connection Services (DCS) Directory
>
> Number of entries in the directory = 1
>
> DCS 1 entry:
>
> Local database name                = DB2INST1
>
> Target database name               = INST1
>
> Application requestor name         =
>
> DCS parameters                     =
>
> Comment                            =
>
> DCS directory release level        = 0x0100

I reset the database by doing `db2stop` and `db2start`

Finally, I ran `netstat -tulpn` and saw the database was listening on port 60000. Output below:

> tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:60000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
>
> 2949/db2sysc

This is as far as I got. From what I can tell I am using the target database name and trying to connect to the correct port number.

Am I barking up the right tree here? Any help is greatly appreciated.

** Edit: Formatted answer to mustaccio's response **

On the server, I go down a level after I ssh on. I get 4 directories named `<USERNAME>,  dasusr1,  db2fenc1,  db2inst1`

From there I did `sudo su db2inst1` then  ran the `db2 list dcs directory command` to get:

```
Database Connection Services (DCS) Directory
Number of entries in the directory = 1

DCS 1 entry:

Local database name                = DB2INST1
Target database name               = INST1
Application requestor name         =
DCS parameters                     =
Comment                            =
DCS directory release level        = 0x0100
```

Comment: Firstly, the DCS directory is used for DB2 on z/OS (which is stated in the link you have included) so changing it won't make much difference in your situation. Secondly, you are possibly confusing the DB2 instance name and database name. Can you show the output of `db2 list db directory` _on the server_?

Comment: On the server, I go down a level after I ssh on. I get 4 directories named `<USERNAME>,  dasusr1,  db2fenc1,  db2inst1`

From there I did `sudo su db2inst1` then  ran the `db2 list dcs directory command` to get: 
    Database Connection Services (DCS) Directory

    Number of entries in the directory = 1

DCS 1 entry:

 Local database name                = DB2INST1
 Target database name               = INST1
 Application requestor name         =
 DCS parameters                     =
 Comment                            =
 DCS directory release level        = 0x0100
`

Comment: It's all good, but, as I say, the DCS directory is irrelevant in your case. Now try `db2 list db directory`.

Comment: Oh Im sorry about that. Here is the output: 

  System Database Directory

 Number of entries in the directory = 1

Database 1 entry:

 Database alias                       = SAMPLE
 Database name                        = SAMPLE
 Local database directory             = /home/db2inst1
 Database release level               = d.00
 Comment                              =
 Directory entry type                 = Indirect
 Catalog database partition number    = 0
 Alternate server hostname            =
 Alternate server port number         =

Comment: OK, so there's your answer. Your database name is SAMPLE, not INST1 or DB2INST1. Put that into your JDBC URL.

Comment: I feel silly now. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while but for other people looking for a solution to this db2 connectivity problem.  If people want to test physical connectivity of their development machine to the db2 server use CLPPlus that comes with the DB2 driver and manually put in the connection parameters to make sure you have physical connectivity.   My environment is quite different than Garret's above but I want to offer one more clue that might help people connect.  I was using VS 2015 enterprise with SSIS.   I used CLPPlus to confirm physical connectivity then started trying to connect and ADO.Net source to db2.  I had to override the port for my server credential  db2server.mydomain.com:523 to override the port to 523.  Then something funny happened.  SSIS was fussing about the connection and I started looking at the parameters.   One of the parameters was Authentication, which you could probably code in jdbc.   I put in DB2 (as opposed to ldap or some other wallet) as the value for Authentication and it worked.

Comment: Dunno if this that tool, but current and just proved useful to me: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/stand-alone-test-programs